# Filter out certain array keys (and their values), while keeping other array keys and values

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out what, if any, is a function to effectively remove a certain set of keys for an array.

I tried chaining array_keys and array_diff, but that just seemed to lead to me getting an array of array keys.

Basically, I want to remove the following keys:

"submit", "form_build_id", "form_token", "form_id", "op", "multi_reg_checkbox"

While preserving the structure of the original data.

Is array_filter what I am looking for? It sounds like it could be, but it seems like it is based on value only.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_diff_key($arr, array_flip(array('foo', 'bar', ...)))
```

http://php.net/array_diff_key

The flip is just for convenience, you could also define the array of keys to remove using `array('foo' => null, ...)`.